# Coding errors when moving the application

Tags: python, gtk3, mingw-w64, pygobject

I am porting an application from linux to windows.
Changing the encoding from utf-8 to windows-1250 doesn't help
event.keyval which reports the following message for Polish letters:

character_e = event.string
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 0: invalid start byte

the event is for the character 'ł' etc which mingw64 interprets as utf-8 (?)

Comment: no need to change it from utf-8 to windows 1250, just use utf-8

Comment: I understand. However, the error still occurs:
does not recognize the Polish characters "ł, ó, ź" presenting the message as above.
I have no ideas.

Comment: then use utf-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `event.keyval` is *not* a string or character.
It is an integer (`guint` to be precise), see [here](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/struct.EventKey.html).

You should probably use the GDK function `gdk_keyval_to_unicode` to convert it. In Python that should be `Gdk.keyval_to_unicode`. It takes one parameter; the keyval.
Like this:

```
character = Gdk.keyval_to_unicode(event.keyval)
```

Comment: It works as it should. For conversia I used var = chr(character). Thanks